# Why is the html not recognising the view function?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build an inventory management with Django.
When building delete option, I am encountering an error.
The error message is "Reverse for 'delete' not found. 'delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

I will paste my code below.

Delete function code:

```
def delete(request, iid):
  obj = inventory.objects.get(id=iid)
  obj.delete()
  return render(request, 'main/lists.html')
```

HTML Template code:

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger bg-gradient" href="{% url 'delete' i.id %}" role="button">Delete</a>
```

Urls.py code:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name="index"),
path('lists', views.lists, name="lists"),
path('add', views.add, name="add"),
path('edit', views.edit, name="edit"),
path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete, name="delet") ]
```

Please give me a valid solution.

Comment: can you share your `urls.py`? you should have a URL that points to this function

Comment: I have updated. take a look

Comment: Have you seen Daniel's answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `urls.py` the url pointing to the method is called `delet`.
Update it to `delete` on `urls.py` or to `delet` on the HTML template.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) you can do this:

```
{% url 'delet' i.id as the_url %}

<a class="btn btn-danger bg-gradient" href="{{ the_url }}" role="button">Delete</a>
```